# Constant rank theorem

Tags: differential-geometry

In Boothby's "An introduction to Differentiable Manifolds ...", page 69, Remark 4.2:

> [image]

I am unable to discover two cubes of same side length, as asked for.
I shall feel very thankful if anyone give some hint.

Comment: Can you please explain your question a little? I am having difficulty understanding your question :(

Answer (score 2):

You are not actually required to describe such cubes. What the remark tells you is that, up to composition by some diffeomorphism, you may *assume* that $\phi(U)$ and $\psi(V)$ are cubes of the same side length. This gives you a way to locally visualise the image of $N$ in $M$.