# Proof that the function $f$ is not injective.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:U\subset\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be a function of class $C^1$ with $m> n$. Prove that $f$ is not an injection function.

I do not know how to solve this problem. Could someone help me with the solution to this problem?

Comment: Idk the answer but I guess that it (probably) is related to the property that differentiability is a local property and that the derivative have a linear local approximation... but as I says it is just a guess (probably wrong).

Comment: I thought first of doing it as absurd, assuming f is injective and then trying to relate in some way to the local form of the submersions, but I do not know how to do it, since I do not know if it is an isomorphism.

Comment: This is referred to as Topological invariance of dimension [see the post by Terry Tao, Corollary 3](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/brouwers-fixed-point-and-invariance-of-domain-theorems-and-hilberts-fifth-problem/)

Comment: Interesting. It's the same problem.

Comment: The blog post doesn't assume continuous differentiability though, so there's probably an easier proof under a $C^1$ assumption.

Comment: Truth. I did not realize that no post did not ask to be C1

Comment: Here you go https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086314/continuously-differentiable-map-from-mathbbrmn-to-mathbbrn/1086462#1086462